# Maintaining and updating data over the life of a database

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm reasonably familiar with maintaining a database schema over time when developing backend applications using migrations. For example, adding a new column means creating a new migration file which will eventually be applied once pushed to production.

However I'm a bit unclear when it comes to one-off data updates. A specific customer might want a minor change to their set of data. Is there a convention in maintaining and recording these specific changes over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't an exact fit for the SO rules, as it doesn't really have a factual answer; it's quite broad and opinion based, so we might pick up a few down votes..

Personally, I'd manage those sort of things like this:

- System has a facility to run SQL directly, locked down
- Support team write an SQL to carry out the work, give to customer
- customer applies the fix/runs the SQL
- any auditing, logging, backup is a task for your system that applies the update. Adopting a similar strategy to migrations would probably be sensible (a table logging what, when and why, so updates aren't repeated)

It could be pretty dangerous to have, as a facility, if it were exposed and free but there are myriad ways to counter that- perhaps you'll make a pub/priv key pair per customer, and encrypt the sql before you give it to the customer, the system will only run sql that decrypts successfully, so while your support team is the only holder of the priv key, only they can write runnable sqls.

I don't think it's sensible or workable to do this in a migrations style workflow, coupled with source control because I can't think of a really good way of keeping the customer specific stuff separate from the core codebase in a way that doesn't become a management nightmare over time

Comment: I'll keep my posts in the future to questions regarding specific problems rather than opinions. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I've no problem answering opinion based questions, as I'm generally more a lover of forum format than SO format, and I don't mind picking up the odd DV of ultimately it helps:) it was just an FYI in case your question gets DV / closevotes. Other denizens of SO are a bit more sticklerish, I'm sure this regarding people like us as littering miscreants :)

Comment: Yeah I can definitely see that around SO, thanks again for the detailed response though. Sometimes I just want to discuss a topic rather than a particular issue I'm having with XYZ framework :).